# boundary condition measure associated to a rotation invariant operator

Tags: boundary-value-problem

According to A. Venttsel  (On boundary condition for multidimensional diffusion processes)
[image]

The measure in $(13)$ is of the form $\nu(drd\theta)\cdot d\varphi$ while in the general case we had

[image]

[image]

The  question is: How do we obtain a measure of the form $\nu(drd\theta)\cdot d\varphi$? Are we using rotation invariance here?